# lazy: true of Lazyload image gem breaks the image for Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, lazy-loading

I'm trying to install https://github.com/jassa/lazyload-rails for my image heavy website.

Image doesn't show when I add the required **lazy: true**

Does syntax need to be different for Ruby on Rails 5?

```
<%= link_to image_tag(post.image_url.to_s, lazy: true), post_path(post), remote: true %>
```

Thank you

---

Gemfile

```
gem "lazyload-rails"
```

application.html.erb

```
<script>
   $("img").lazyload();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to download [jQuery Lazy Load Plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.js) script and place it under `vendor/assets/javascripts`